# Installing ROS Kinetic on OSX Sierra

Tags: osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So, I am trying to follow  http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/OSX/Homebrew/Source

Any I am just getting error after error. Has anyone got Kinetic working on Sierra

I have tried mikepurvis/ros-install-osx
I had to open an issue
https://github.com/mikepurvis/ros-install-osx/issues/78

> Make Error at
> /Users/burfies1/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/cmake_modules/cmake/Modules/FindPoco.cmake:186
> (MESSAGE):   Poco was not found.  Set
> the Poco_INCLUDE_DIR cmake cache entry
> to the   top-level directory
> containing the poco include
> directories.  E.g
> /usr/local/include/ or
> c:\poco\include\poco-1.3.2 Call Stack
> (most recent call first):
> CMakeLists.txt:15 (find_package)
>
> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! See also
> "/Users/burfies1/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/class_loader/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
> <== Failed to process package
> 'class_loader':    Command
> '['/Users/burfies1/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh',
> 'cmake',
> '/Users/burfies1/ros_catkin_ws/src/class_loader',
> '-DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/Users/burfies1/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/class_loader',
> '-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/Users/burfies1/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated',
> '-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release', '-G',
> 'Unix Makefiles']' returned non-zero
> exit status 1
>
> Reproduce this error by running:
> ==> cd /Users/burfies1/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/class_loader &&
> /Users/burfies1/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh
> cmake
> /Users/burfies1/ros_catkin_ws/src/class_loader
> -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/Users/burfies1/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/class_loader -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/Users/burfies1/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated
> -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -G 'Unix Makefiles'

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254267/installing-ros-kinetic-on-osx-sierra/) by [burf2000](https://answers.ros.org/users/28716/burf2000/) on ROS Answers with karma: 202 on 2017-02-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [david.romanos](https://answers.ros.org/users/29357/david.romanos/) on 2017-02-14**:
I have the same exact problem installing Indigo. Did you manage to solve it?

**Comment by [burf2000](https://answers.ros.org/users/28716/burf2000/) on 2017-02-14**:
No sadly, if you do, please let me know

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-14**:
Not an answer, but have you seen [mikepurvis/ros-install-osx](https://github.com/mikepurvis/ros-install-osx)?

**Comment by [burf2000](https://answers.ros.org/users/28716/burf2000/) on 2017-02-14**:
@gvdhoorn I must owe you a beer by now.  Sadly it dies but thank you.  I am still stuck on my bloody wheel issue

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-14**:
I see you've opened an issue there. Please include a link in a comment on your original question to keep issues connected.

Issue: [mikepurvis/ros-install-osx#78](https://github.com/mikepurvis/ros-install-osx/issues/78).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same issue,  I used brew install poco.
Also I was able to get ROS to run on my Mac Sierra with the bare-bone packages installed.(ie. no graphing, visualization)
the tutorial is here: http://qiita.com/YoitsuKamijo/items/246683401e08d785a6ce

---

Originally posted by [yoitsukamijo](https://answers.ros.org/users/30131/yoitsukamijo/) with karma: 16 on 2017-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [burf2000](https://answers.ros.org/users/28716/burf2000/) on 2017-04-25**:
Mine is trying to use Python 3.6? so I get a str issue

**Comment by [yoitsukamijo](https://answers.ros.org/users/30131/yoitsukamijo/) on 2017-04-25**:
which command caused that error?